# Would a blind city have windows?

Tags: society

I've made it so they have the ability to echolocate and for the main character, a person with sight, the lighting is odd because it only comes from fires that are a necessity for warmth, cooking or forging.

My question would be, would windows be of any use in a windy city?

Comment: Title says blind, body says windy city. Which of the two?

Comment: define windows, would they have transparent glass no would they have things they can open to let in fresh air yes.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica both

Comment: @MisterOnion Then, please, [edit] your question to be clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure how they'd figure this out, but if they did... sunlight [is a natural disinfectant](http://sunlightinstitute.org/sanitizing-with-sunlight-the-best-disinfectant-know/). Dark places are much more conducive to breeding mold and other nasty stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Ventilation and temperature control

The windows are probably not going to look like modern windows, with nicely tempered glass, but if we're defining a window as something you can open that's not a door then you'd probably want them still. Depending on climate these might look like shutters, sliding metal panels, or even just holes in the walls.

EDIT: good airflow is going to be particularly important if you provide warmth with indoor fires.

Answer (score 4):

## Ventilation

You'll want some form of windows to help stay cool in the summer and to help give you enough fresh air to fuel the fireplaces. Here's a [detailed guide](https://www.windowmaster.com/solutions/natural-ventilation/natural-ventilation-design-guidelines) to window ventilation and below is a diagram from [here](http://bcapcodes.org/tools/code-builder/commercial/ventilation/).

[image: Diagram of natural air flow]

If there's a fireplace in every room, you also want to think about how your people will escape if there's a fire. You might want to have windows or other openings in larger buildings to make it easier to get out.